# CakePHP: hasMany with join table

Tags: cakephp, relationship, cakephp-model

I have two models: `Store` and `Review`. Users of my site can leave a review on a store. In my database, I have a join table, `reviews_stores` that associates a review with a store.

How do I link my models? I assume a `Store` should haveMany `Review`, and a `Review` should belong to a `Store`, but the join table is causing issues with CakePHP as CakePHP is assuming my `reviews` table has a column called `store_id`.

The reason I'm using a join table is because many parts of my site can be reviewed. For example, brands. A new `Review` record will be created and a record will be inserted into a `brands_reviews` table to associate the two records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me it isn't a many-many relationship but a grouped 1-many relationship. Id lose the join tables and simply have an extra table outlining which 'group' the review belongs to. So the review table would have review_id, link_id(the foreign key for the relevant brand or store), review_type_id(foreign key depicting whether the review is for a brand or store and so on). Then the review_type table only needs to have review_type_id, review_type(varchar).

Comment: So in the `review_type` table, would `review_type` be something like `Store` or `Brand`?

Comment: That would be how I'd do it yeah. Then if you add more 'review_type's in future theyll just get a new idea. Effectively its a basic categorisation system for reviews similar to how a new categorisation system would work only that each review can have only 1 review type

Comment: Thanks, @mattwadey. Accepted your answer as you were helpful but more importantly, not an ass about things.

Comment: @MartinBean How was I an ass about things? My answer reflects the structure that the Cake devs use to create their multi-model plugins.

Comment: It wasn't aimed at you, @Dunhamzzz.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not simply using one Review model and a reviews table with a field "foreign_key" and another field "model"? By this you do not need to duplicate tables and inherit or duplicate models. This will also remove the need for a join table.

If you want to continue to use your db design then you'll have to use a HABTM association over the hasMany association. But even in the case you want to keep that jointable, again, you can use the foreign_key/model and simply have one join table and one reviews table.

By the way, your join table review_store does not follow the conventions, it should be reviews_stores. But then it differs to the schema you've used for brands_reviews. ;)

Comment: Because reviews can be associated with other models too, such as a brand as in my example above. The join table associates a review to a store, but it could be a brand or a sale or a blog post etc.

Comment: Well, as I said, this is not necessary if you use two fields (foreign_key, model) and combine them. If you use uuids you do not even need the model field. The join table is *not* necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for all the join tables for each model you can review, simple store the model name itself in a field in the `Review` table.

Setup your relationship like so:

```
class Store extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Review' => array('conditions' => array('Review.model' => 'Store')
     );
}
```

You can then do this with as many extra models as you like without having to touch the database.

Comment: Thanks, @Dunhamzzz. But what happens in the model name were to change? i.e. from `Store` to `Shop` as a simplified example?

Comment: `UPDATE Reviews SET Model = 'Shop' WHERE Model = 'Store'`